# (Objective-C)Is it safe to redefine self within class method?

Tags: objective-c, pointers, initialization, self

Is it safe to reinitialise self within a class method?

```
MyClass * a = [[MyClass alloc]init];

@implementation MyClass
{
    -(id)init
    {
        if(self = [super init])
        {
            ...
        }
        return self;
    }
    -(void)redefine
    {
         //??
         self = [self init];

    }

}
```

will `a` point to the reinitialized instance of MyClass?

Thank You,
nonono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Provided** that (a) your class and its superclasses can be re-`init`'ed without leaking memory or resources and (b) you know that your class and its superclasses `init`s all return the `self` they are passed and not a reference to some other object, then yes...

Otherwise things will go wrong. Consider your `redefine` method; in the body of this method `self` is just a local variable whose contents is initialized to point to some object. Changing the value in that local variable does not change the object it originally pointed at, or the value of any other variables which point to that object. E.g. consider the variation:

```
@implementation Q
{
    - (void) redefine
    {
         self = [[Q alloc] init]; // changes the *local* self to refer to a new object
    }
    ...
}

...
Q *someQ = [[Q alloc] init];     // allocate an object
[someQ redefine];                // NO effect on someQ, another Q is just created and leaked
```

Clearly this does not alter `someQ`, and your version may not either. Your code will have the effect you wish *if and only if* you know `init` always returns the object it was passed - which is not guaranteed in Obj-C.

Comment: before I do self = [self reinit]; can I release - [self release]?

Comment: Nooo! At least as far as I understand what you are trying to do - that is re-init an *existing* object so that all existing references to it see it re-init'ed. If you `[self release]` and then `[self redefine]` you are re-init'ing an object you just released - once you release an object you _cannot_ continue to use it! Indeed doing a `[self release]` anywhere is literally suicide (an object is killing itself) and is likely to cause grief.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `init` returns `self`, which it normally does, nothing will go wrong.

But you probably want to split your initialization to some separate method, which you can call from both `init` and `redefine`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your new object from `-init`, not simply assign a new value to self. And you must remember to release the old self, since it was created with `+alloc`. Caveats aside though, returning a different object from `-init` is explicitly allowed. That's why you'll see newbies being corrected when they write something like this:

```
// Bad example! Do NOT do this!
Foo *foo = [Foo alloc];
[foo init];
```

This is an anti-pattern because `-init` is *not* required to return the same object it was called on. That means the above can end up assigning foo to point to an object that's been released, instead of to the object that was initialized in its place. This is why you always see `+alloc` and `` `init `` chained together like so:

```
Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
```

It's also why you need to reassign self when calling super's `-init`, because it may also have returned a different object.

```
self = [super init];
```